# Event during an annimation tkinter python3

Tags: python, events, animation, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm programming a little game with tkinter and I need get events during main animation. My annimation is a kind of infinite loop like that :

```
def animation(self):
   while 1:
      ...
      ...
      ...
      self.view.get_canvas().uptdate()
      self.view.get_canvas().after(20)
```

I did 2 test with bind function, the first one :

```
self.main_canvas.bind("<Button-1>", print)
```

In this case, when I click on my canvas, the event is printed on the terminal
So, I realized event are detected during infinite loop

2nd test :

```
self.main_canvas.bind("<Button-1>", sys.exit)
```

In this case, when I click on the canvas, nothing happened.
Look likes pretty weird

My questions are :
  Why "print" works and sys.exit doesn't ? 
  why "print" works but my "home-made" function doesn't ?
  How's it possible to execute my owns functions during the animation ?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do animation with an infinite loop. The GUI already has an infinite loop running -- `mainloop`. Your loop is preventing mainloop from being able to process events.

The right way to do animation is to write a function that does one frame. Then, have that function call itself using `after`:

```
def animation(self):
    ...
    <redraw the scene>
    ...
    self.after(20, self.animation)
```

With that, all events will be handled in the 20 milliseconds between each frame.

Comment: Thanks, but how I can do for manage variables ? And other question, does tkinter interpret this kind of loop like recursive ?

Comment: @Epitouille: it is not recursive. You are simply adding new events (a "run me" event) to a queue. As for managing variables, I don't see how this has anything to do with that. If you need variables to persist from one frame redraw to the next, simply store them as properties on the object.